# QTP/UFT - Store Browser().Page() as Variable

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Is it possible to take this line of code:

*Code:*

```
Browser("site").Page("site").WebElement("xpath:= ((//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]))[1]").HighLight
```

And do something like this:

*Code:*

```
WebLink = Browser("site").Page("site")

WebLink.WebElement("xpath:= ((//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]))[1]").HighLight
```

I think in terms of readability where you have a TON of code, this would read much better. You only have to declare this once and call the variable.

Unless there is a better way I just haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a link explaining how to solve my scenario shortly after posting the question, but decided to leave it open simply for the way the question is phrased for future newbies..

*Link:*

[Buildup and reference of objects in HP UFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789693/buildup-and-reference-of-objects-in-hp-uft)

This lead me to the below solution:

*Code:*

```
Set WebLink = Browser("site").Page("site")

WebLink.WebElement("xpath:= ((//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]))[1]").HighLight
```